# Flutter Carousel no Image and some other difficulties

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

I am new to flutter as well as app dev.
I was trying to implement a STAEFUL carousel that responds and redirects to a certain link when an image in the carousel is clicked.

Here are the problems I faced.

1. I am not getting how to make the carousel images stateful should I implement a Gesture detector or Inkwell?
2. Should Every image has to be tagged within the [LIST] or the entire carousel can be tagged with a single inkwell or gesture detector?
3. Please have a look in the code, is it possible to map the redirect addresses as a list! (This will be much easier to add images, but what is bothering me here is, do I have to recompile and upload the app to AppStore each time I add new image address and respective redirect link?)
4. Most importantly the carousel isn't showing the images only the URL [image: noimage in carousel]

5. what do these mean in this part of the code?

***[LIST].map((i) {}***

and

***'text $i'***

```
 items: [imgList].map((i) {
          return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueAccent),
              child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
          );
```

***here is the entire code***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
//import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_options.dart';






 List<String> imgList =

 [
   'https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg',
   'https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png',
];







 List<String> redirectList =
 [
   'img 1 redirect link',
   'img 2 redirect link',
 ];      //yet to be configured








class VerticalSliderDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: CarouselSlider(

        options: CarouselOptions(
          aspectRatio: 2.0,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          autoPlay: true,
          autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
          autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
          autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,

        ),


        items: [imgList].map((i) {
          return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueAccent),
              child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
          );
        }
        ).toList(),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Amit506/courouselexample

in this link i have uploaded correct working courousel slider .
if you want to know the differenve between text widget and image widget you should refer to official documentation of flutter they have written all the information of widgets.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html

https://github.com/Amit506/dart-foods/blob/main/lib/TabBars.dart/TabBar1.dart

in this link i have used courousel builder in one of my project you can refer to it for advance courousel slider.

Comment: Ohhh! I was getting it wrong from the beginning, My thoughts were that the MEDIA QUERY will fetch whatever it gets from the list like Img or Vids.  I was also wondering If I don't mention the list items with indexes then it will automatically fetch them serially. I have understood that I have to Wrap each banner of the Carousel inside gesture detector, so I can redirect appropriately. Thank you for the Example code I really appreciate it. ///////another questions am having regarding the NEXT PAGE, Is it possible that the Next page to be a PDF which can be read inside the app ?

Comment: mediaQuery fetches things about your device like height availabe.Also you are using wrong way using map if you want to build courousel from list without writing item again and again you should use courousel.builder widget.

Comment: yes I have noticed that in the repository but that is not clearly explained at least not for me, I am still unable to find out the no 5 question.

Comment: yes it is surely possible to show pdf you will have to design the next page to show particular pdf . you will get plugins related to pdf and give it a try if you get problem you can ask me.

Comment: Thank you for being so kind and helpful I will certainly try and if I got stuck I will surely let you know.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for bothering you again as you said I tried implementing on demand carousel but  I am not understanding what to do with ** ctx ** & **index ** in this following code. I was thinking that it will automatically get the list but there are no words of how to map the list.  If  it automatically  maps the list then what is the need of the INDEX ??     `itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return Container(child: Text(index.toString()),
              );`    and is it possible to Map the whole carousel inside one gesture detector? otherwise, the code becomes lengthy with repetitions.

Comment: Index is here just to refer the item to take from List like if index is 0 then first item of List will be build and indexes are increased one by one till the itemCount proeprty reaches its limit. In itemCount you have to write yourlistname.length() so it can know number of indexes it has to go and to refer your list item you have to write yourlistname[index].

Comment: ItemCount :             yourlistname.length( ) ,                                   
     itemBuilder :     (BuildContext , int index) {  return 
    Container(child:Text(yourlistname[index].toString()), 
      );

Comment: woow, that works I had no idea how to map list, thanks for that concept, please help me with another thing should I create a list of "NEXT PAGES " and map those also with indexes or as you have suggested in my another question regarding firebase to build a database , so is there any simpler way with databases?

Comment: one more help please can you tell me where I am wrong, why can't I use multiple "child" it shows error.
                
                        child:
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
                          
                          child: Text(imgList[index].toString()),
                          child: Image.network  (imgList[index], fit: BoxFit.fill),
),
`

Comment: you can"t use multiple child in Container .To use multiple child use column as a child in container then in column you can write as much children you want to.

Comment: oh, thanks for the clarification, it wasn't stated in docs that container doesn't take muli child. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show picture in text widget.for showing image from url you have to use Image.Network () instead of text widget. text widget is used to show only text .
to show any network image you can do
Image.Network('url'). If u want i can can show you code

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry, but I am unable to understand where is the text widget is holding the images, the images should be fetched by the "item" property which is getting the URLs from the list, am I wrong there!  and about imge rendering  MediaQuery is taking care of that? have I misunderstood?

Comment: From item property you are just providing  url ..not image wait i will upload correct code .

Answer (score 0):

To make image responsive to tap you  only have to wrap image widget with gesturedetector /inkwell or any other widgets available  In this case you can wrap image.Network

Comment: if I do so how can different images take me to different pages? can they be mapped to different URLs depending on the banner clicked?

Comment: Yes it will be. i'll show you how it will be done